# AWS China hadoop master - S3DistCp command to copy hdfs files to S3 is throwing NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/internal/Pair

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

1) We are trying to use S3DistCp jar (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html#emr-s3distcp-verisons) for copying the hdfs files from AWS China hadoop master instance to AWS China S3 bucket.

2) We are running following command from AWS China hadoop master

```
hadoop jar /usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp.jar --src hdfs://${HDFS_DIR} --dest s3n://${S3_BUCKETNAME}/${Folder_Name}/ --s3Endpoint=s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn
```

3) Following exception is being thrown when we run this "s3-dist-cp" command

```
16/02/22 08:39:52 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Using output path 'hdfs:/tmp/f6a864f8-d70d-426f-b05f-08f7d0097fd9/output'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/internal/Pair
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.getSrcPrefixes(S3DistCp.java:468)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.createInputFileList(S3DistCp.java:521)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:850)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.internal.Pair
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

4) Also can you please let us know if there are any other alternatives then using "s3-dist-cp" for copying hdfs files from AWS China hadoop master instance to AWS China S3 bucket ?

Thanks and Regards,

Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the AWS China Hadoop EMR cluster we had created had some problem. We have created new AWS China Hadoop EMR cluster and using the "s3-dist-cp" command we are now able to upload HDFS files from AWS China Hadoop master to AWS China S3 Bucket

//Example of s3-dist-cp command

s3-dist-cp --src=hdfs:///HDFS_Folder_Name/ --dest=s3n://my-bucket/folder